# Run a PHP script using Jquery with webstorm

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Firstly, thanks so much in advance for any help you might be able to give me one this!

Right, what I want to do, is to call a php script to run server side, which takes in a single value (which will be an email) and write it to a text file.

This is the .php file that I want run. I haven't finished it yet, but after hours of trying I can't even seem to get it to create this text file, and write "test"to it.

```
<html>

<?php
  $myfile = "GatheredEmailAddresses.txt";
  $fopen2 = fopen($myfile, 'a');
  $stringData = "Here";
  fwrite($fopen2, $stringData);
  fclose($fopen2); 
?>
Done!
</html>
```

So far, I've only made any sort of progress using this. I know it loads the file, because it displays the text "Done!" in the div area called content area, however I just can't figure out why the rest isn't running. This is the jquery I am using(obviously all relevant tags such as  etc are included above:

```
$("#compute").click(function()
    {
       $('#contentArea1').load('test.php');
    });
```

I'm not even going to bother asking about the email side of things yet, just want to know how I can run this using jquery. 
Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

Hi guys,

After trying some stuff this morning, I've identified that it must be a problem with how my php file is being run. When I run it in my IDE, it runs perfectly, creates the file and works fine. However, when I run it using a Jquery post, it simply returns the "TEST TEXT" and displays it in the relevant div. I'm running it using a "load" jquery command. Any ideas? Very frustrated! :(

This is the php file:

```
<?php
 $dir = 'myDir';
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
      mkdir ($dir, 0777);
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', 'Hello File');
?>
TEST TEXT
```

Comment: Has the text file been created already?

Comment: Hi Eoin, good thought! Yes it has, and it is not open in notepad or similar so that isn't it either..

Comment: Does php have permissions to write to the file?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm not sure. I'm looking into that now and will let you know, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using is_writable() ?

Comment: have you tried accessing the page directly and checking the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments. I suspect it may be permissions issue. I'm going to look into that and then revisit this with either the solution or hopefully more information on the error.

Comment: Morning gents! I've updated the error above ^

Answer (score 1):

You could use `file_put_contents()` instead of all the fopen, fwrite and fclose functions, it would make it much easier to understand :)

Also you need to SEND the data to the PHP file (via AJAX, GET/POST). I can't see you doing that anywhere.

Also - any permissions issues need to be sorted. But I still recommend `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: Hi Leigh, as I say, before I even attempt that I'd like to know that it runs and at least creates the text file

Comment: $handle = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 'w' means we want to write :)

Comment: I think perhaps you could try getting the PHP part for writing to a file working first (google: PHP write to text file), and once that's working each time you run the page, then you can start doing the jQuery AJAX after.

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery part, you can use $.get

```
$.get("test.php", { email: "myFirstEmail" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/